# Putting cooldown to an interaction button

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to put a cooldown function to my interaction button.

This is my base code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class CookieButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, label="", custom_id="cookie", row=0)
    
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user) # this doesn't work but want to make it work samely. (5 second cooldown)
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        view: CookieView = self.view

        view.cookie += 1
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"You have {view.cookie} cookie(s) .", view=view)


class CookieView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.add_item(CookieButton())
        self.cookie = 0


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command(name="cookie")
async def _cookie(ctx: commands.Context):
    view: CookieView = CookieView()

    await ctx.send("You have 0 cookie .", view=view)

bot.run("token")
```

In this, i want to make callback function to be executed every 5 seconds per user.

How can i make it work as i intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom cooldown for this using:

```py
cd_mapping = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(10, 10, commands.BucketType.member)
```

```py
class CookieView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.add_item(CookieButton())
        self.cookie = 0
        self.cd_mapping = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(10, 10, commands.BucketType.member)
```

And then check if member is rate limited in your `callback` function:

```py
async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    view: CookieView = self.view
    bucket = view.cd_mapping.get_bucket(interaction.message)
    retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
    if retry_after:
        return await interaction.response.send_message("Sorry, you are rate limited.", ephemeral=True)
    view.cookie += 1
    await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"You have {view.cookie} cookie(s) .", view=view)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving the user pressing the button temporarily (like a blocked list) and when a user presses the button, you compare the userid with the id‘s on your list. You can make a dictionary when the user pressed the button the last time and compare it to a new timestamp.
To make the button work, you can remove the reaction to the discord message immediately if your user is on the list.